# Concatenate and Replace with VBA on Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone point me in the right direction with code or keywords to lookup? I am trying to concatenate, add email, and replace:

| Example | Names |
| --- | --- |
| Example 1 | FirstName1 LastName1, FirstName2 Lastname2, FirstName3 Lastname3 |

Into something like:

| Example | Names |
| --- | --- |
| Example 1 | FirstName1.LastName1@email.com, FirstName2,Lastname2@email.com, FirstName3.LastName3@email.com |

Names will be separated by commas.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are the names all in one cell?

Comment: `nameArray = Split(ws.Cells(2,2).value," ")` would help you get concatenate with `Step 2` while looping through your `nameArray`

Comment: As this is tagged `vba`, please edit your post to include the code you've tried thusfar.

Comment: First split on comma to separate the users, then split each element of that array on space, or just replace space with `.` and tack on `@email.com`  Then join the first array with a comma+space

Answer (score 1):

Please, use the next function:

```
Function processNameMailAccount(x As String)
  Dim arrNames, i As Long
  Const domain As String = "@email.com"
  
  arrNames = Split(x, ", ")
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrNames)
        arrNames(i) = Join(Split(arrNames(i)), ".") & domain
  Next i
  processNameMailAccount = Join(arrNames, ", ")
End Function
```

It can be used/tested in the next way:

```
Sub testprocessNameMailAccount()
   Dim x As String
   x = "FirstName1 LastName1, FirstName2 Lastname2, FirstName3 Lastname3"
   Debug.Print processNameMailAccount(x)
End Sub
```

Supposing that the column having the names is "B:B" you can use the function to process as you need with a code like the next. For testing reasons, it returns in column "D:D":

```
Sub processNames()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
  lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  arr = sh.Range("B2:B" & lastR).Value2
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        arr(i, 1) = processNameMailAccount(CStr(arr(i, 1)))
  Next i
  'drop the processed array result in D:D:
  sh.Range("D2").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).Value2 = arr
End Sub
```

If it returns as you need, you can change "D2" from the last code line in "B2" and the initial values in B:B will be replaced by the processed strings...